# Is is safe to let Ubuntu resize my Windows partition during installation?

Tags: hp, system-installation

I have a HP Pavilion 15-n077so laptop with Windows 8.1. I want to keep Windows but I want also install Ubuntu. I think this is uefi laptop, so is there anything to take care about before installation?

This machine has one 1TB hard drive with one partition so I should somehow give some space to Ubuntu. Can I let Ubuntu installation make partitions safely?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, but as with anything that involves data: make sure you have your data backed up.

Remember, as far as we know this works out of the box but nothing is guaranteed against faults!